# Why is jh_magnificpopup not working on my site?

Tags: typo3, magnific-popup

On my site jh_magnificpopup is no longer working. jQuery seems to be there but still it is not happy... Why is this?

http://www.wannermech.ch/schlosserei/diverse-gebrauchsgegenstaende.html

Comment: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function..

pull down templates of jh_magnificpopup at last in the root template > include tab.

Comment: it is the last already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two different versions of jquery in your site:

in the beginning (line 29):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in the end: (line 94):

```
<script src="typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-c586b8f41a42376a91eae317eb6f66f9-5c96191b865a8f66f661743685d8e702.js?1540748008" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which includes jQuery v2.2.3.

In such a case even the noConflict option

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery.noConflict();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

might induce more confusion

Comment: The first one I have included myself. The second I have no idea where this comes from. Perhaps jh_magnificpopup includes this automatically somehow?

Comment: the first is included explicit, the second one also includes some JS for HTML5audioplayer (NIMIUS). As it is named `typo3temp/assets/compressed/merged-c586b8f41a42376a91eae317eb6f66f9-5c96191b865a8f66f661743685d8e702.js` it might be used in some compressed `includeJS`

Comment: I still did not manage to solve this. I now completely deleted the NIMIUS extension. But still I have the $ is not a function error...

Comment: you can use a browser console to get more hints about your javascript problem. another way to identify the culprit: disable extension by extension until your error is gone, then inspect the extension which introduces the error (or the other way around: disable all, then enable one by one)